# How to settle a rave payment in escrow

Tags: api, payment-processing, flutterwave

I'm trying hard to find the latest way to settle a payment in escrow and the docs seem to be outdated.

The [rave v2 docs clearly show](https://developer.flutterwave.com/v2.0/docs/escrow-payments#settling-an-escrow-payment) that the endpoint https://api.ravepay.co/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle should settle a pending escrow payment, however, a 404 error comes up instead.

I've tried using `https://rave.flutterwave.com` and `https://ravesandbox.flutterwave.com`

No docs I can find show the right API endpoint to settle escrow payment.

Note: there's an older answer on this platform but it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Flutterwave docs dont do a good job telling that this is a POST method, not GET.

```
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
        
    let data = {
        "id": txid,
        "secret_key": "your-secret-key"
    };

    fetch('https://api.ravepay.co/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle', options)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(response => console.log(response))
       .catch(err => console.error(err))
```